# How do I correctly concatenate 3 dataframes extracted with a loop in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate 3 tables extracted from 3 webpages from the internet in Python. The webpages are called xxxxx1, xxxxx2, and xxxxx3. All 3 databases have a shape of (60,26). So the shape should be (180,26) after concatenating all 3 databases. My problem is that it remains (60,26) after concatenating. Probably showing only the table from the last URL (xxxxx03)?:

```
for i in range(1,4):

    name_r1 = ('xxxxx'+ i)

    r1 = requests.get(name_r1)

    dfs1 = pd.read_html(r1.content)
    
    df=pd.concat(dfs1)
    

df.shape
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either append to a list and then concatenate after everything. Because `pd.read_html` returns a list of DataFrame we will use `itertools` to chain them all together so we are concatenating DataFrames, not lists of DataFrames.

```
from itertools import chain

l = []
for i in range(1, 4):
    name_r1 = ('xxxxx'+ i)
    r1 = requests.get(name_r1)
    l.append(pd.read_html(r1.content))
    
df = pd.concat(chain.from_iterable(l))
```

Or do it in a succinct list comprehension:

```
df = pd.concat(chain.from_iterable([pd.read_html(requests.get('xxxxx'+ i)) 
                                    for i in range(1, 4)]))
```

---

The above would be equivalent to creating the DataFrames by concatenating the output of `pd.read_html` and then joining all of those DataFrames after the loop.

```
l = []
for i in range(1, 4):
    name_r1 = ('xxxxx'+ i)
    r1 = requests.get(name_r1)
    l.append(pd.concat(pd.read_html(r1.content)))
    
df = pd.concat(l)
```

Comment: With your suggestion of the list I get TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'list'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

Comment: @MiguelAngelGonzalez let me know if that update works.

Comment: It works and I appreciate it... I would like to know what the problem was and why your chain.from_iterable makes it work. Thanks a lot

Comment: @MiguelAngelGonzalez `pd.concat` expects a list of DataFrames/Series so `pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])` works. But read_html returns a **list** of DataFrames so it sees something like `pd.concat([ [df1, df2], [df3, df4] ])` and instead it sees a list of lists (of dataframes). All that chaining does is flatten that hierrchy so `[*chain.from_iterable([[df1, df2], [df3, df4]])]` is  `[df1, d2, df3, df4]`